# RTS game engine for iOS/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, rts

Anyone know any free or non-free RTS engine that can be used for iOS game development?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an engine dedicated to RTS, but there's always Unity3D. Runs on both iOS and win.
If you plan on iPhone/Pad development it's going to cost quite a bit though. That being said, Unity is quite awesome!

Comment: Even at the highest cost, $4,500 (Pro, iOS Pro, and Android Pro) is not all that expencive for the level of polish on the Engine... that said, it is quite steep for a start-up and/or hobby game.

Answer (score 1):

[Glest](http://glest.org/glest_board/) uses OpenGL.  You could port it to the iPhone.